# How to link .sql file with my netbeans project with XAMPP?

Tags: java, sql, xampp

The proccess of importing a .sql file from phpMyAdmin is easy. However even though I everything the right way and get a "Successful import" message, when I try to run my project in NetBeans I am always in the same point. The java programm doesn't recognize any database.
Should I have the MySql installed in my PC or something else?? What should I do??